# GtkCss: Naming objects by id in CSS doesn't work

Tags: css, c, gtk

I have a simple XML code generated by Glade and loaded using GtkBuilder:

```
...
<object class="GtkIconView" id="iconbar">
  <property name="visible">True</property>
  <property name="can_focus">False</property>
</object>
...
```

and I am trying to change the background of #iconbar using a CSS file like this:

```
#iconbar { background-color: #111; }
```

This, however, doesn't work. I can only change the background color if I change #iconbar to GtkIconView in the CSS file (.GtkIconView identifier doesn't work either).

The application code is very simple:

```
GtkWindow* main_window = ...;
GtkCssProvider* css = gtk_css_provider_new();
gtk_css_provider_load_from_path (css, "dark.css", NULL);
gtk_style_context_add_provider_for_screen (gtk_window_get_screen(main_window), GTK_STYLE_PROVIDER(css), GTK_STYLE_PROVIDER_PRIORITY_APPLICATION);
```

Could someone tell me, what am I doing wrong?
Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `name` property, e.g.

```
<property name="name">iconbar</property>
```

Then you should be able to refer to the widget as `#iconbar`.

Comment: Thank you, the code now finally works. Setting <property name="name" ...> just because of identification is quite ugly, though. What is the purpose of object "id" generated by Glade, then?

Comment: The ID is for referring to the widget in the `GtkBuilder` object. Once the widget is created, the ID doesn't exist anymore, I believe.